# AWS DynamoDB not returning response to Lambda function

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am working with serverless and NodeJS using the aws-sdk module, and I have been getting a `502 internal server error` on the frontend of the app, previously it was shown as a cors error but so far it is the same issue in only one specific table when performing update or delete. Here is the Lambda function itself:

```
export async function createUserSegment(event, context, callback) {
  const { data, timestamp, identityId } = extractRequestData(event)
  console.log('data', JSON.stringify(data));
  if (!verifyParamsExist(callback, ["Data", "IdentityId"], [data, identityId]) ||
    !verifyParamsExist(callback, ["Name", "Pattern", "Type"], [data.name, data.type, data.pattern]) ||
    !verifyValidParams(callback, [data.name, ...data.pattern], ["Name", "Pattern"], [{ value: data.type, enums: USER_SEGMENT_TYPES }], ["Type"])) {
      console.log('no good params');
    return false
  }

  let cleanedParams
  let params

  try {
    cleanedParams = cleanUserSegment(data.pattern, data.type)
    console.log('cleaned params', cleanedParams);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
    callback(null, badRequest({ type: "InvalidRule", status: false, msg: e.message }));
    return
  }

  params = {
    TableName: process.env.USER_SEGMENT_TABLE,
    Key: {
      "cognitoUsername": fetchSubFromEvent(event),
      "segmentName": data.name.trim(),
    },
    // Performs an insert (fails if already exists)
    // - 'cognitoUsername': cognito username (NOT IDENTITY ID!) of the segment creator.
    // - 'segmentName': user-provided name to identify the segment
    // - 'createdAt': unix timestamp for when segment is created
    // - 'pattern': user-supplied pattern that the segment refers to
    // - 'segmentType': either VISITED, NOT_VISITED, GOAL, NOT_GOAL to indicate what our pattern is matching (URL visits or goal completion)
    // - 'identityId': cognito identity id of the segment creator.  necessary for querying ES
    UpdateExpression: 'SET pattern = :pattern, segmentType = :segmentType, createdAt = :createdAt, identityId = :identityId',
    ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(cognitoUsername)',
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":pattern": cleanedParams.pattern,
      ":segmentType": cleanedParams.type,
      ":createdAt": timestamp,
      ":identityId": identityId,
    },
    ReturnValues: "ALL_NEW"
  };


  writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates(params, callback, transformUserSegment)

}

async function writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates(params, callback, transformFn){
  try {
    if(params.ConditionExpression){
      console.log(params);
    let result = await dynamoDbLib.call("update", params);
    console.log('this is res',result);
    result.Attributes = transformFn(result.Attributes)

    callback(null, success({ status: true, result: result }));
    } else {
      await dynamoDbLib.call("update", params);

      const paramsForAll = {
        TableName: params.TableName,
        KeyConditionExpression: "#cognitoUsername = :username",
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
          "#cognitoUsername": "cognitoUsername",
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
          ":username": params.Key.cognitoUsername
        },
      }

      try {
        let result = await dynamoDbLib.call("query", paramsForAll);
        result.Items = result.Items.map(transformFn)
        console.log(result);

        callback(null, success({ status: true, result: result}));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
        callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
      }
    }
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)

    if(e.code === 'ConditionalCheckFailedException'){
      callback(null, badRequest({ type: "Duplicate", status: false }));
    } else {
      callback(null, failure({ status: false }));
    }
  }
}
```

The `call` function for `dynamoDbLib` is simply:

```
import AWS from "aws-sdk";

AWS.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

export function call(action, params) {
  const dynamoDb = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  return dynamoDb[action](params).promise();
}
```

The request goes through the Lambda up until within `writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates` the `call` function is made. it gets sent to dynamo but it never returns, neither a timeout nor an error, it simply ends. In cloudwatch the last thing I see is the params log from `writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates`, no error logged. I hadn't changed the IAM policies on the role assigned to all Lambdas with the following permissions for the table aforementioned:

```
...},
          {
            "Action": [
              "dynamodb:UpdateItem",
              "dynamodb:Query",
              "dynamodb:Scan",
              "dynamodb:DeleteItem"
            ],
            "Resource": [
              "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxx:table/staging-userSegmentTable"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
          }, 
    { ...
```

If anyone spots anything that might be a possible reason for the issue, it will be much appreciated.

---

Also here is the last log shown before the END message on LOG events:

```
2020-01-07T23:42:03.715Z    4fbf0957-c8be-4520-8277-7b9a9bda8b67    INFO    { TableName: 'staging-userSegmentTable',
  Key:
   { cognitoUsername: '*******************************',
     segmentName: 'cssfs' },
  UpdateExpression:
   'SET pattern = :pattern, segmentType = :segmentType, createdAt = :createdAt, identityId = :identityId',
  ConditionExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(cognitoUsername)',
  ExpressionAttributeValues:
   { ':pattern': [ '/' ],
     ':segmentType': [ 'CONTAINS' ],
     ':createdAt': 1578440523709,
     ':identityId': '****************************************' },
  ReturnValues: 'ALL_NEW' }
```

which corresponds to `console.log(params)` before sending to DynamoDB inside the if statement of the `writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates` function.

Comment: Could you help show the "params" log of "writeToDynamoAndCatchDuplicates" function? And which line the application stopped?

Comment: Hi Phan, I just added the params log. It stops there without showing any error from Dynamo, it simply sends it but there is no response back. I even increased duration and memory for the function but it only took 173.78 ms.

Answer (score 0):

Does your IAM have Read and Write Access to that Database and security group connected to the instance? Is this the only table that seems to be the issue?

I had a similar issue ended up having to give my DB instance full read access.

Comment: Yeah, the IAM role for the lambda function had read access, and I even attached the AWSLambdaFullAccess policy to the role which is supposed to provide full access to all services like dynamo under `"dynamodb:*",` and `"Resource": "*"` (which is a little overkill but wanted to test).

Just as odd, it is the only table with that issue on write access (`delete`, `update`) but it has no issues with read (through `query`) since it returns all the results from related to a user but it does not processes any edits or deletions.

Comment: @AxelKaban this doesn't seem to be an AWS issue if all other tables are reading and allowing write access then I think you could look into you database user permissions. I hope this helps, I understand the struggles with lambda and RDS very frustrating.